# How to get bottom of user stack under multi threads on Linux

Tags: c, linux-kernel, stack

I would like to get user stack information on 64bit Linux.
I know mm->start_stack that indicates a location of an initial stack pointer of user stack.

However, under multi thread applications like a pthread, mm->start_stack is the same values all threads because of using same struct task_struct.

And, I know the way of memory layout by using mm->mmap->vm_start and mm->mmap->vm_end but, I do not know that whether these mmap area are stack or not.

I confirmed memory layout under these with pmap process id and strace.

Could you tell me how to get user stack location all threads like a mm->start_stack?.

```
sudo pmap 24074
24074:   ./a.out
0000000000400000      4K r-x-- a.out
0000000000600000      4K r---- a.out
0000000000601000      4K rw--- a.out
0000000000602000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00007ffff5fee000      4K -----   [ anon ]
00007ffff5fef000   8192K rw---   [ anon ]   <==== Thread Stack
00007ffff67ef000      4K -----   [ anon ]
00007ffff67f0000   8192K rw---   [ anon ]   <==== Thread Stack
00007ffff6ff0000      4K -----   [ anon ]
00007ffff6ff1000   8192K rw---   [ anon ]   <==== Thread Stack
00007ffff77f1000   1792K r-x-- libc-2.23.so
00007ffff79b1000   2044K ----- libc-2.23.so
00007ffff7bb0000     16K r---- libc-2.23.so
00007ffff7bb4000      8K rw--- libc-2.23.so
00007ffff7bb6000     16K rw---   [ anon ]
00007ffff7bba000     96K r-x-- libpthread-2.23.so
00007ffff7bd2000   2044K ----- libpthread-2.23.so
00007ffff7dd1000      4K r---- libpthread-2.23.so
00007ffff7dd2000      4K rw--- libpthread-2.23.so
00007ffff7dd3000     16K rw---   [ anon ]
00007ffff7dd7000    152K r-x-- ld-2.23.so
00007ffff7fda000     12K rw---   [ anon ]
00007ffff7ff6000      8K rw---   [ anon ]
00007ffff7ff8000      8K r----   [ anon ]
00007ffff7ffa000      8K r-x--   [ anon ]
00007ffff7ffc000      4K r---- ld-2.23.so
00007ffff7ffd000      4K rw--- ld-2.23.so
00007ffff7ffe000      4K rw---   [ anon ]
00007ffffffde000    132K rw---   [ stack ]
ffffffffff600000      4K r-x--   [ anon ]
 total            31108K
```

strace results

```
clone(child_stack=0x7ffff77efff0,flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7ffff77f09d0, tls=0x7ffff77f0700, child_tidptr=0x7ffff77f09d0) = 24075

clone(pid: 24074 child_stack=0x7ffff6feeff0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7ffff6fef9d0, tls=0x7ffff6fef700, child_tidptr=0x7ffff6fef9d0) = 24076

clone(child_stack=0x7ffff67edff0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7ffff67ee9d0, tls=0x7ffff67ee700, child_tidptr=0x7ffff67ee9d0) = 24077
```

Comment: `mm->start_stack is the same values all threads because of using same struct task_struct.` - Partially wrong: on Linux every thread uses **its own** `task_struct`. But `mm` is probably shared between threads from the same process.

Comment: Thank you. You're absolutely right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't completely well-defined. Technically, a user may create a thread using `pthread` and then switch the new threads `sp` to another one. So the stack created by `pthread_create` isn't always the stack used by the process. Hell, the process may even `munmap` it...

You can, however, access the user's stack at a specific moment (e.g. syscall), in the following manner:

```
task_pt_regs(task)->sp
```

However, be sure to validate it, as it may not always be in userspace. The user has complete control over it.

Answer (score 0):

Most systems provide `pthread_getattr_np` (Linux) or `pthread_attr_get_np` (NetBSD) or similar means to initialize a `pthread_attr_t` structure from a running thread.

Once you have done that, you can use e.g. `pthread_attr_getstackaddr` and `pthread_attr_getstacksize` to get the lowest address and the size. The "bottom" of the stack is either the former or the sum of both, depending on the direction of stack growth.

Small note of warning: while many systems provide this functionality, it may or may not work for the initial/main thread of a program. You have found one Linux specific way of dealing with this already.